Book in which a spaceship crashes on a planet with sentient vegetation and the crew is followed by an unfriendly alien
A ship crashes on a planet with poisonous vegetation. The crew is followed by an unfriendly alien, trying to catch them. The vegetation helps the crew to reach the ship. The vegetation turns out to be sentient and working against the alien.
Anybody know this book? I read a Czech translation of it in the seventies.

This could be a "Nemesis From Stars" by Hans Kneifel,
original german title Nemesis von den Sternen.
Czech translation (possibly multiple publishings over the years) came as a book with 2 stories in: Cerna Planeta / Nemesis z Hvezd
Roughly (Google) translated from german book plot description:

Skogamandry is an ancient planet covered by dense vegetation. Orr Jong and Vance Carnaghan had spent the last two hundred days surveying and surveying the planet. They are already eagerly waiting to finally be picked up when a discus ship of unknown origin has to make an emergency landing. They are able to save the pilot, but his appearance reminds them of an old legend of the Star Peoples - the Nemesis from the stars that plagued large parts of the galaxy eons ago. And the strange pilot does everything to ensure that his unwanted discovery remains a secret.

The plot description does not mention vegetation being sentient
specifically, but I remember that from the story clearly.

Thank you so much, big help!
